# Implementation of Manual Approval in Continuous Delivery using Kubernetes and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-delivery

Currently I am trying to implement examples for both continuous delivery and deployment using Kubernetes and Jenkins. I have successfully implemented continuous deployment. Automatically, my REST API is deploying to my Kubernetes cluster via Jenkins. Both test and prod namespaces are deploying.

Now I am trying to implement continuous delivery by making a manual user approval before releasing to prod namespace. Means implement a manual approval by implementing one switch in between test and prod environments.

For more clarity I am adding here screenshots I got while I am exploring,

**Continuous Delivery & Continuous Deployment Difference in Manual Approval**

[image]

[image]

Here my confusion is that, when I am implementing the delivery, how I can add the user interaction?  Do I need to change any parameter in my `deployment.yaml` or `service.yaml`? Or do I need to change anything when I am creating my Jenkins pipeline job in Jenkins UI?

I am new to the continuous delivery side. Can anyone suggest any documentation or tutorials or any method to explore please?

Comment: What do you mean by "making a user interaction"?

Comment: Manually Need to approve the deployment to prod after deployment to test. In delivery release upto prod is not automated. In between that , need to manually allow by making a switch in between that.  That manual process I meaned here. I hope that you can understand what I am trying to say. Thank you for your response for my discussion sir.

Comment: If you are using Jenkinsfile - this can be achieved using https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/

Comment: @VishalBiyani - If you update this information as answer clearly , I can mark this as answer. I already implemented and successfully I am deploying with manual approval to production version. Thank you for your response sir.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob - added answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Jenkins Input Step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) to do something like this. Input step coupled with a `try/catch` will enable you fairly good control over success/failure of the job also.

The [example below is from CloudBees support](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230922428-Pipeline-How-to-add-an-input-step-that-continues-if-aborted-using-value) portal and uses the input box, captures the input and uses that input value to set the success/failure of the current build

```
def userInput
try {
    userInput = input(
        id: 'Proceed1', message: 'Was this successful?', parameters: [
        [$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', defaultValue: true, description: '', name: 'Please confirm you agree with this']
        ])
} catch(err) { // input false
    def user = err.getCauses()[0].getUser()
    userInput = false
    echo "Aborted by: [${user}]"
}

node {
    if (userInput == true) {
        // do something
        echo "this was successful"
    } else {
        // do something else
        echo "this was not successful"
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using a shared library in Jenkins. We will pause the pipeline for 1 day and send mail to Approval DL mention in AD with the link. If not approval timely we will terminate deployment.

Approval has to login jenkins using the link to the approval of the deployment. (we thought about direct approval link but it is a security risk.)

```
timeout(time: 1, unit: "DAY")
{
  log("Send an email to approvers@example.net with link)
  sendEmail()
  def inputResult = input (
  id: "123", 
  message: "I approve this deployment",
  )
}
```